# dm-script command to change cursor pointer

Tags: user-interface, cursor, dm-script

Is there a DM script command to change cursor pointer? Somehow my program changed the cursor to the cross for "Rectangle ROI". I need to find a way to get the cursor out of ROI mode through command, that is, back to the arrow selection pointer.

Comment: This sounds to me a bit like you have inadvertedly set the "default tool" to the rectangluar ROI. Whenever you "finish" a tool (also the ROI tool) it will revert back to this "default". See below. You can change this both by regular UI interaction and by script commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **No, as far as I know, mouse-cursors cannot be addressed by DM scripting.**

How did you end up in your situation? If it was by "regular use" it might well be a bug worth reporting at the Gatan webpage:

- [Gatan Webpage: Software service overview](http://www.gatan.com/resources/software)
- [Gatan Webpage: Issue & bug reporting form](http://swbugs.gatan.com:9821/ttweb/loginsolosubmit.htm)

Otherwise, I could imagine that either a custom-plugin developed by the SDK (i.e. a custom .dll in the plugins-folder) or changes with your overall OS setting could influence the displayed cursor. Have you checked this?

---

> ### There are script commands to change the currenlty active tool.
>
> DM knows two types of *set tool*:
>
> - The *current tool*: This is the currenlty active tool, i.e. what the mouse will do
> - The *default tool*: This is the tool to which the cursor will return once the currenlty active tool has finished its action
>
> In **GMS 3+** one sets 
> the *current tool*: by selecting it with the left-click mouse button from the right-click menu tool bar
> the *default tool* : by keeping the ALT key pressed while selecting the tool as above
>
> In **GMS 1 & 2** one sets 
> the *current tool*: by selecting it with the left-click mouse button from the tool bar
> the *default tool* : by selecting it with the left-double-click mouse button from the tool bar

For scripting, each tool as a numeric 'ID' which can be used to set the tool. The according commands are:

```
Number GetCurrentToolID(  )
Number GetDefaultToolID(  )
void SetDefaultToolByID( Number toolID )
void SetCurrentToolByID( Number toolID )
void RevertToDefaultTool(  )
```

I have not tested it, but it is likely that the behaviour of the commands - and maybe also the exact tool ID values - differ between GMS 3 and earlier GMS versions.

Comment: Those toolID commands perform exactly what I wanted. I haven't figured out why my script does that. With those command, I can now force it go out of ROI mode. Thanks. Problem is solved.

Comment: I found the reason that tool was set to ROI tool. It is due to this command , `ChooseMenuItem( "Analysis", "Particles", "Start Threshold" )` in my script. It is not a bug, it is by design of DM. I bypassed the manual ROI selection on histogram with script control. So, DM does not exit the ROI tool state when the script is done. `SetCurrentToolByID(0)` does the trick to return the active tool state to "move".

Comment: @user6406828 Thanks for clarification. That makes sense.